# Implement CRUD operations of an MVC application based on a REST architecture

Tags: model-view-controller, rest, crud

As I understand, a RESTful API aims to provide a communication layer for building on top of an application. Could the core application be build using the same REST logic?

So for example, build the REST architecture, and then implement all the database operations (CRUD) based on REST.

Therefore in an MVC application we have some controllers for implementing the REST service, like:

```
function Users(user_id){
    \\ return user with id = user_id
}

function Articles (article_id){
   \\ return article with id = article_id
}
```

And some controllers for handling the presentation. So if for example we want to list some articles in the homepage:

```
function homepage (){
   for ($i=0; $i<10; $i++)
   {
      \\ request  'http://www.example.com/articles/' . $some_article_id;  
   }
   \\ output to view
}
```

Not sure if the above makes sense, but the main point is that we add another layer in the MVC architecture, so that the ***presentation-logic Controllers*** no longer communicate directly with the models, but only through the ***REST Controllers***:

In an MVC approach the data flow is:

*presentation Controller* ----> *Model* ----> *presentation Controller* ---->  *View*

In an MVC - REST approach the data flow would be:

*presentation Controller* ----> *REST Controller* ----> *Model* ----> *REST Controller* ----> *presentation Controller* ----> *View*

Do you see any disadvantages in the above approach? I believe that it would simplify coding but I searched a lot and haven't found any further info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there are many disadvantages.
 - HTTP is intended for transfer of large grain resources.
 - Implementing database transactions across HTTP requests is problematic, to say the least.
 - You are using HTTP where is really isn't necessary and potentially introducing performance issues

and architecturally it is just the wrong place to use REST.  See [this](http://www.jroller.com/rickard/entry/rest_api_for_infrastructure_domain) article for a more in-depth discussion of why you should not attempt to expose your domain objects using REST.

Comment: In the past few days I'm switching from CodeIgniter to Rails and also read [this article](http://tomayko.com/writings/rest-to-my-wife). Now I see how silly my question was.

Comment: @Zack  You're question was not silly at all.  I would say the majority of people attempting to implement REST apis are making the same mistake.